# Connect Android phone to router via USB-to-Ethernet

Tags: usb, networking, htc-desire-hd

I own an HTC Desire HD and it currently has the IceColdSandwich custom rom on it. I also own a usb OTG adapter and a D-Link USB 2.0 Fast Ethernet adapter DUB-E100.

What I want to achieve is to connect my phone on a Cisco Router with that "cable sequence"(Phone -> USB OTG adapter -> USBtoETHERNET dub-e100 -> ethernet cable -> Router) and be able to sustain a telnet connection between the two in order to give network configuration.

In order for this to work I definitely need to enable the USB host mode on my device through kernel.

Let's say I can get my kernel to work do I need the usbnet driver with my combined hardware for the dub-e100 to work? or maybe there is really no way for this to be done?

any ideas on alternative ways to do this?

-edit-
There are many reasons why one would want to do this. For example, testing an ethernet port in an office building without having to lug around a laptop. Another, be able to configure a router that does not have wireless, or one that you can't access the wireless on (maybe you butterfingered the encryption key on the AP) 
-edit- by Izzy

Comment: For identifying alternative ways it would be good to know why you need Ethernet on a Smartphone.

Comment: [How to make Ethernet work on Android over OTG?](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/225741/218526)

Answer (score -2):

Check out the App [Ethernet on Google Play](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=xda.usbhost.test). You will need to root your phone though.